# How to set '5 day' (datetime interval) in jdbc for PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Considering the following example

```
select * from foo where time +'10 day' >current_timestamp
```

I would like to make this query parametrized for Java, and I don't know how to set the `10 day`?! (String doesn't work)

Comment: Have you tried `select * from foo where time + 10 >current_timestamp`?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from foo where time +'10 day'::interval >current_timestamp;
```

Answer (score 20):

You may either pass a String parameter and cast it, e.g.

```
select * from foo where (time + CAST(? AS interval)) > current_timestamp
```

or pass an int parameter multiplied by a fixed interval, which is better if you're always working with days not more complex intervals. E.g.

```
select * from foo where (time + ? * INTERVAL '1' DAY) > current_timestamp
```

with a `setInt` parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Be sure to write the query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE "time" > current_timestamp - interval '1 day' * n
```

The point is to compare the column to an expression, so the whole thing is [**sargable**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) and an index can be used.

Either pass a the readily calculated `timestamp` for `current_timestamp - interval '10 days'`, or pass an *integer* for `n`.

And I would not use `time` as column name, which is a [reserved word in the SQL standard](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

[More about date / time arithmetic in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: want to have parameter in current_timestamp so my ? comes in place of current_timestamp..please help.. for example, SELECT * from foo WHERE "time" > TIMESTAMP ? -interval '1 day'; how to pass ? in such case from JDBC

Comment: @AshaKoshti: Please ask your question as *question* - providing the necessary context.