# Why can I not parse the interval as a parameter in JPA?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to select the timestamp interval:

```
@Query(value = """
    SELECT timestamp as time_start, timestamp + interval ?1 as time_end
    FROM timestamp_table
""", nativeQuery = true)
List<TimestampTable> findTimestampIntervals(String interval);
```

Why does this not work? I keep getting this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
```

The string interval value I'm testing with is "1 day". If I hardcode the value instead of injecting it, it works perfectly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058684/org-postgresql-util-psqlexception-error-syntax-error-at-or-near-1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set '5 day' (datetime interval) in jdbc for PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998959/how-to-set-5-day-datetime-interval-in-jdbc-for-postgresql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't bind the time string which follows `INTERVAL`.  But, you can use the following trick:

```java
@Query(value = """
    SELECT timestamp as time_start, timestamp + (?1 * interval '1 day') as time_end
    FROM timestamp_table""", nativeQuery = true)
List<TimestampTable> findTimestampIntervals(String interval);
```

To the `?1` placeholder you may bind an numerical variable corresponding to the number of days you which to add.  The above approach is necessary because Postgres, unlike most other SQL databases, doesn't provide a direct date adding function.

Comment: But i don't necessarily want to add days, I might want to add one hour

Comment: @Ben Then change `'1 day'` to `'1 hour'`?  I'm not seeing the problem here.

Answer (score 2):

Although the syntax INTERVAL '30 minutes' is valid when you write SQL directly in a console, it is actually considered to be an interval literal and won't work where the string that follows the word INTERVAL is not a literal string.

Prepared statements in PostgreSQL are implemented on the server side using PREPARE and each ? is seen as an actual variable on the server. This is also why it complains about $1 although you never wrote a $ in your statement.

Therefore, literal syntax does not work for a prepared statement.

Don't let the string representation (result of println) of the prepared statement confuse you - it's not what the server sees. The server sees a variable there.

Thus, you need to use syntax that takes a string (which can be a variable or a literal) and converts it to interval. For example ?::INTERVAL or CAST(? AS INTERVAL).

This is therefore not a bug.