# INTERVAL expression in Spring Data JPA Native Query

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, spring-data-jpa

I have Spring JPA.

I have a query ***like*** this in sql oracle:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE  SYSDATE > MY_DATE + INTERVAL '10' DAY;
```

I have a CrudRepository in which I use the above query in native mode, ***like*** this:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, 
            value = "SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE  SYSDATE > MY_DATE + INTERVAL :myValue DAY")
public List<Object[]> myMethod(@Param("myValue") String myValue );
```

I get ORA-00933:

Passing myValue as integer between quotes I get ORA-01867

Passing myValue as integer without quotes I get ORA-00933

How to do it?

Comment: Checked the accepted [answer trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68033607/why-can-i-not-parse-the-interval-as-a-parameter-in-jpa)?

Comment: @Pp88 thx! yes it fits, I did not find the question/answer searching by google, the only difference is the ":" instead of "?" because of oracle instead of postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments on question, there is a similar question/answer for spring/jpa/postgresql, solution for me is:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, 
            value = "SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE  SYSDATE > MY_DATE + :myValue * (INTERVAL 1 DAY"))
public List<Object[]> myMethod(@Param("myValue") int myValue );
```